# Is there a graphical query builder tool for Neo4j to explore the graph and do RCA

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was wondering if some one knows of a tool for neo4j that lets the non developers to query the neo4j database without having to learn cypher. basically to do some sort of root cause analysis when they see some thing strange.

An hypothetical example could be that we model our our store operations on the neo4j and all the transactions are recorded in the neo4j db through our application, but when the store owner sees that there is a consistent missing inventories on the store he may want to start doing some RCA without needing to learn cypher. may be ask neo4j to show all the employees on a particular day, and then pick an employee and ask for all the days in last 6 month when that employee was in store and what was the deviation in inventory etc.

I know i can make up such queries using cypher, but would be hard to ask the end users to learn that, so is there any graphical tool that will let them do such analysis on their own, paid or otherwise?

Regards

Comment: I did try to search the net and found very little information there and that's the reason for this post. I was really not aware that we can't ask the community if anyone has used/knows of any tool that can fulfill some common needs. Having to build a tool from scratch seems very counter intuitive when someone knows of any open source project or commercial tool that does the same thing. I am not really looking for an opinionated answers here, but some suggestions to start my analysis. is it really off topic to ask for such a request, or can this be reworded to pass this rule?

Comment: Have a look at http://maxdemarzi.com/2013/01/28/facebook-graph-search-with-cypher-and-neo4j/ for an example of turning a Natural Language Query into Cypher. We are about to use Treetop to do this also...

Comment: I think there is: https://github.com/Nhogs/popoto

Answer (score 4):

As far as graphical tools go, you could use the Neo4j 2.0 browser but that would require a set of favorite Cypher queries to bring in the base set of data for your analysis. There are a few visualization tools out there but none that I know of would be perfect for your scenario.

I recommend that in this case you would assemble a set of template queries that take a range of parameters. Each question that your employees would want to ask would be translated to Cypher in advance and the front end of your application would allow your users to specify the ranges and other pertinent parameter information for each one of your questions.

> may be ask neo4j to show all the employees on a particular day, and
>   then pick an employee and ask for all the days in last 6 month when
>   that employee was in store and what was the deviation in inventory
>   etc.

Show all employees who worked on a particular day.

```
MATCH (e:Employee)-[:WORKED_ON]->(d:Day)
WHERE d.Date = "11/24/2013"
RETURN e.LastName, e.FirstName, e.EmployeeId
```

Your parameter here would be `d.Date` and your `e.EmployeeId` would be used as a parameter for the next query.

```
MATCH (e:Employee)-[:WORKED_ON]->(d:Day)
WHERE e.EmployeeId = {EmployeeId} AND d.Timestamp > 123456789
WITH e, d
MATCH (e)-[:WORKS_IN]->(s:Store)-[:ON_DAY]->(d)
WITH e, d, s
MATCH (s)-[:HAS_INVENTORY_DEVIATION]->(delta:InventoryDeviation)
RETURN e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName, e.LastName, d.Date, d.Timestamp s.StoreLocation, delta.Deviation
ORDER BY d.Timestamp DESC
```

In the query above you would supply the `EmployeeId` from the first query and the `d.Timestamp` value would represent a timestamp as a 32bit integer. In this case the value `123456789` would represent the datetime value of 6 months ago from today's date.

Comment: well this was just an example to explain my thoughts, but the intent was that we want the actual end user traverse the graph and draw conclusions without having to learn cypher for simple analysis like this. Kind of things we see in the SQL world where there are some graphical query builders tools to generate simple ad-hoc reports with minimal knowledge of the data model. Is there any tools out there that can help them build the query and execute. having to define all possible questions some one can ask the system might be a bit too much work upfront.